# Homoscedasticity test for repeated measures ANOVA, SPSS

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, heteroscedasticity

My experiment has three treatments, looking at different measures of animal behaviour in response to each treatment.

Firstly, is testing for `homoscedasticity` for a repeated measures `ANOVA` necessary? I've seen different pages suggesting this is or isn't an assumption of the test.

I thought it was necessary to plot `residuals` on Y against X, but if so how should you do this for repeated data on `SPSS`? (e.g., scatterplot of residuals with treatment 1 on y against treatment 1 on x - not sure this is correct).

Or, secondly, is it not necessary because `sphericity testing` does this for me on the repeated measures `ANOVA`? I'm a bit confused whether these are the same thing or not.